# Laravel hasMany error. 'site_id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, dingo-api

I have following method in a controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $site = Site::create([
        "path" => $request->path,
        "site_link" => $request->link,
    ]);

    if ($request->features) {
        $features = explode(',', $request->features);

        foreach ($features as $feature) {
            $site->features()->save(SiteFeature::create(["feature" => $feature]));
        }
    }

    return response()->json($site, 201);
}
```

Site model has this method

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SiteFeature');
}
```

And this is my `$fillable` property of a `SiteFeature`

```
protected $fillable = ['feature', 'site_id'];
```

By some reason I get next error

> local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'site_id'
>   doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `site_features`
>   (`feature`) values (fes)) {"exception":"[object]
>   (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: HY000): SQLSTATE[HY000]:
>   General error: 1364 Field 'site_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL:
>   insert into `site_features` (`feature`) values (fes))

Comment: You're adding a row, but site_id doesn't have a value to insert, nor does it have a default in the database schema, so the INSERT fails.

Comment: you cant put two model pls?

Comment: you are using this `protected $fillable = ['feature', 'site_id'];` so you need to provide value for `site_id`, otherwise alter the table and add a default value for column `site_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Model::create` method actually creates a record in your database and since you're not specifying a required `site_id`, it is failing which is why you're seeing this error.

It looks like you're trying to use Laravel's relationships to save a new `SiteFeature` for the site but you're passing what would be an already existing object (if the query didn't fail) to the relation's `save` method.

You need to either pass a *new* instance of `SiteFeature`, that has not already been saved to the database to the [`save`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method) method:

```
$this->features()->save(new SiteFeature(['feature' => $feature]));
```

or you can use the relation's [`create`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) method to avoid having to pass in an instance altogether, you just need to provide the attributes:

```
$this->features()->create(['feature' => $feature]);
```

Comment: $site->create() should create a hasMany relationship record so it should provide site_id itself

Comment: In which case you're not using the relationship to create the entity, I will update my answer.

Comment: The problem was that I was trying to create a DB record to site features using eloquent instead of creating model instance.

Answer (score 0):

try this

in your model `features`

```
public function features()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\SiteFeature','site_id','id');
}
```

you model `SiteFeature`

```
public function siteFeatures()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\features', 'site_id', 'id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$site = Site::create([
    "path" => $request->path,
    "site_link" => $request->link,
]);
```

Doesn't return the last insert id... try

```
$site = new Site;
$site->path = $request->path;
$site->site_link = $request->link;
$site->save();
```

As for this part:

```
if ($request->features) {
    $features = explode(',', $request->features);

    foreach ($features as $feature) {
        $site->features()->save(SiteFeature::create(["feature" => $feature]));
    }
}
```

You could do this if the above code doesnt work...

```
if ($request->features) {
    $features = explode(',', $request->features);

    foreach ($features as $feature) {
        $sf = new SiteFeature;
        $sf->feature = $feature;
        $sf->site_id = $site->id;
        $sf->save();
    }
}
```